# Possible to automatically sync SQLite from Wearable to Mobile?

Tags: android, sqlite, wear-os

I am experienced with using the WearableDataAPI to synchronize both settings and other game information between Watch and Wearable. In fact, currently certain information gets persisted in the DataAPI which works great until you need to reset the watch or mobile.

I would like to convert to using SQLite to store the data on the Mobile. Is there a way of inserting into a Wearable SQLlite database and it automatically replicating to the Mobile? Or would I need to code the data transmission myself using the DataAPI?

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is now such implementations for common databases.

In my practise, DataAPI might lag while syncing huge (>100kB) files, it consumes battery too.

Use MessageAPI in order to improve the performance for message transfer and create two separate databases on both handheld and wearable using common API.

Or, much better, use only one handheld API and tranfer data from handheld into wearable device using MessageAPI each time when you want to render something on your watches.

Comment: Yeah , this is the default direction I was heading. I'll probably refactor the handheld to use SQLite and continue to use the DataAPI for game-by-game transfer ("game" as in upcoming soccer game). I just finished refactoring that from "transfer one large DataItem of games" to "transfer one DataItem per game" to avoid the 100KB limit.